# Form doesn't display on browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have this code, and using codeigniter, I used form_open() to print form on the browser as you can see below.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary panel__add-dept">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>LIST OF DEPARTMENT</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <?php echo form_open("organization_control", ['id'=>'org-create']);?>
        <?php form_close(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary panel__add-pos">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>LIST OF POSITION</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <?php echo form_open("organization_control", ['id'=>'org-create']);?>
        <?php form_close(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the next form after above, still using form_open(), but the form tag is not display on the browser.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <?php echo form_open("organization_control", ['id'=>'org-create']);?>
        <?php form_close(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using `<form>` instead of `<?php echo form_open(); ?>` but I get the same result, this is the first time I encounter this problem, I check jquery and css, But it doesn't contribute the problem.

I tried to copy paste code above, some row display form while other still has the problem not showing the form tag on the browser.

Have you tried this?

Comment: shouldn't "id" be unique? And shouldn't it be "**echo** form_close();"?

Comment: @Fil load form helper first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[form_close()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_close)

> Returns:   An HTML form closing tag
>
> Return type:   string

Therefore, you should use echo prior to it.

```
echo form_close();
```

Since you don't actually close your first form and you can't have nested forms - things are getting problematic.

Further more, consider that the `ID` attribute should be unique per page, so use a different value for the second form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load `form` helper.You can load it either in controller using

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

**OR**

in `appliaction/config/autoload.php`. using

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

The `Form` Helper file contains functions that assist in working with forms.

For more see docs [Form helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: Since the OP mentioned that the second form isn't being created yet the first one does, I assume the helper is already being loaded. No?

Comment: yea but also in his first form there is only `<?php form_close(); ?>` obviously it not work .

Answer (score 0):

echo your form_close func

```
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Also, you can check if there are unclosed tags by viewing source in the browser.